# Double side PCB with solder via?

Tags: soldering, via

Normally vias are made with through hole plating. In the past they used to make vias by soldering a piece of wire to connect the top and bottom layers (like a short piece of 24 gauge copper wire). Could the same be done with solder?

Question: Can a VIA in a double sided PCB be connected with solder? Is there any precedent for  such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not, but I think you will find that it's easier to assemble with wire. The trouble I suspect is heating both sides of the board simultaneously such that you can get the solder to flow on both sides, then overcoming the surface tension of the solder and getting it to go through the hole. That, and solder is more expensive than wire.

Comment: Solder is also more resistive than copper.

Comment: Copper vias it is.

Answer (score 1):

I personally do it this way. To use solder is much, much faster than a wire. Imagine you have 50 or 100 vias which you have to fill. I think either way is OK as long as the speed does not concern you. Quality is the same and it does the job anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible because surface tension will prevent solder from filling unplated vias especially small ones (less than a couple millimeters). As RF4 material repells solder.